# python - VIDLE can't import

Tags: python, import, python-idle

It's a very simple problem, though perhaps the solution is not so obvious. In the shell of VIDLE, the version of IDLE with visual stuff added, I cannot import a package on a separate line from using that package.

Specifically, I can't do:

```
>>> from visual import *
>>> b = box(vector =(0,0,0), color=(1,0,0))
```

This gives a "NameError" because it can't find "box".
However I CAN do:

```
>>> from visual import *; b = box(vector =(0,0,0), color=(1,0,0));
```

This brings up a window with the red box in it, but I can't do anything else with the box until I close the window (i.e., I'd have to add further instructions onto the end of this, but what I'd ideally like to do is do them all on separate lines and play with the box rather than execute a chunk of code over and over).

I'd like to know how to import all the things in visual once for the shell, and then be able to call things from it on subsequent shell commands.

EDIT: Specifically, after the "from visual import *" call, the shell restarts. When it isn't given the chance to restart (i.e., in debug mode, or by putting the instructions in sequence) it seems to be able to use the import. However, debug mode freezes, and when I put them in sequence, it restarts the shell after the sequence has completed, thus nullifying the import.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Vidle; restarting seems like a bug you should maybe report.  Is the problem specific to 'import *' (generally discoraged for a couple of reasons). What happens is you use 'import visual as v' and continue with v.box?